# How to create a Thread in a Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I'm fixing an existing rails web application. This application call the Index method of the controllers when a url is called. This Index calls another method from a module which last about 10 seconds, so the view isn't showed to the user until this module method finish. I have tried to execute the module method in a new thread in this way:

```
Thread.new do
  ModuleFoo.MethodFoo
end
```

but it continues waiting the 10 seconds and then showing (or rendering) the view to the user. It's this behavior normal? What should I use instead?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I presume the `ModuleFoo.MethodFoo` call isn't essential to the rendering of the view? If not, you'll likely want this processed as a background job - have a look at [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) for examples of popular handlers.

Comment: Sidekiq is another popular option too.

Comment: Yes, MethodFoo is not essential. Thank you for the links!

Comment: Rails also has [Active Job](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) which comes with [adapters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters.html) for several backends.